# ¿Cómo llamar un método de una clase desde el main de otra clase?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase llamada ***TadArbolBinario*** que tiene el siguiente método:

```
  public void InsertarNodo(Nodo raiz, int dato) {
        if (raiz == null) {
            Nodo nodo = crearNodo(dato);// Creamos el nuevo Nodo llamamos a el metodo crearNodo para que se cree un nodo con el valor del dato.
            raiz= nodo; // El nodo se vuelve la raiz.
        }else{
            int valor= raiz.dato;// cogemos el valor de la raiz
            /**
             * Si el dato es menor que la raiz se inserta al lado izquierdo 
            */
            if (dato < valor) {
              InsertarNodo(raiz.izq, dato);
            /**
             * Si el dato es mayor que la raiz se inserta al lado derecho
            */
            } else {

                InsertarNodo(raiz.der, dato);
            } if (dato == raiz.dato) {
                System.out.println("El dato ya esta en el arbol");
            }
        }
    }
```

Quiero llamar a este método desde otra clase, desde dentro de el método ***main*** que contiene lo siguiente:

```
 Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        TadArbolBinario arbol = new TadArbolBinario();
        int OpcionMenu = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("1. Insertar un elemento al Arbol. ");


            System.out.println("Digite el numero que desea: ");
            OpcionMenu = leer.nextInt();
            switch (OpcionMenu) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Agregue un elemento al arbol: ");
                    int dato = leer.nextInt();
                    arbol.InsertarNodo(arbol.getRaiz(), dato);
                    break;
   } while (OpcionMenu != 1);
```

En ese caso lo estoy llamando pero no me da bien... Como hago para llamarlo ... Gracias

Comment: Tu código esta muy fragmentado. Sólo tendrías que instanciar una clase para usar sus métodos públicos desde el main de otra, pero veo que dices que tu clase se llama Arbolen y estas instanciando TadArbolBinario. Por favor, revisa tu pregunta. Si al compilar / ejecutar no tienes errores pero el programa no hace lo que esperas, tendras errores de lógica, no es un problema de llamar a los métodos de otra clase.

Comment: Pero si esta bien implementada la manera en la que llamo a ese metodo en la main ...en el caso 1?

Comment: Según se ve en el código, llamas al método aquí: `arbol.InsertarNodo(arbol.getRaiz(), dato);` ¿Que si está bien? Eso depende de lo que hace el método `getRaiz()` de la clase `TadArbolBinario`. Tal y como es llamado, parece que el mismo: 1. **No necesita ningún parámetro**. 2. **Devuelve un objeto `Nodo`**. Si es así, no tienes problemas, si no es así, el código fallará. ¿Por qué? Pues no será difícil esbozar una respuesta.

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta (estrictamente a lo que preguntas) es que lo haces bien, creas un objeto del tipo TadArbolBinario arbol y a través de ese objeto llamas al método InsertarNodo. Ahora ya, dando un paso más adelante, como dice A.Cedano, para ver si te funciona bien y hace lo que desees habría que ver el resto de código.

Comment: Prueba a pasar el modo `debug` y sigue la ejecucion paso a paso, iras viendo lo que hace tu programa poco a poco de esta manera podras ver con mas exactitud donde esta ocurriendo el error.

Comment: El metodo insertarNodo se llama a si mismo? Que es lo que hace realmente el metodo?